# Webservice SOAP com PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

Estou com uma dúvida:
Já usei *webservice* Json Curl com PHP e no consumo me retornava um *array* onde eu conseguia trabalhar com as informações, agora aprendendo SOAP o retorno não é satisfatório como no JSON, o máximo que consigo é um retorno XML em uma única linha. Alguém tem alguma dica? Segue meu script:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://minhaurl.com.br?wsdl",
              array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,'trace' => true,"encoding" => "utf-8","features" => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,"exceptions" => true));
       $param = array(
                       'versao'      => '3.0',
                       'cod_input'   => 'C',
                       'cartao'      => 'xxxxxxxxxxx', 
                       'proxy'       => 'x',
                       'usr'         => 'xxxxxx',
                       'pwd'         => 'jS1_Njg2b8b0WMbU' );

        //nome do método
       $resultado = $client->consulta_disponivel($param);
       echo "<pre>\n";
       print_r ($resultado);
       echo "</pre>\n";   
     //Aqui obtenho o retorno:

    stdClass Object
               (
               [return] => LUIZ ALBERTO43326200004787200000000
               )
        //Usando: 
        $result1 = ( $client->__getLastResponse());
         var_dump($result1 );
        //Obtenho:
               array(1) {
                   [0]=>
                   string(701) "<G_ServApp_Response><consulta_disponivel><nome>LUIZ ALBERTO</nome>                                      <cartao>4332620000478720</cartao><proxy>0</proxy><limite_credito>0</limite_credito><disponivel_saques>0</disponivel_saques><disponivel_compras>0</disponivel_compras><saldo_atual>0</saldo_atual></consulta_disponivel><codigo_retorno>00</codigo_retorno></G_ServApp_Response>"
                  }
```

Como consigo "capturar" apenas os dados como no JSON:

```
Array->nome;
   Array->cartao;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode converter o retorno XML para um objeto com a função **simplexml_load_string**

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
 <title>Forty What?</title>
 <from>Joe</from>
 <to>Jane</to>
 <body>
  I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
 </body>
</document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

print_r($xml);
?>
```

O exemplo acima irá imprimir:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
  [title] => Forty What?
  [from] => Joe
  [to] => Jane
  [body] =>
   I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
)
```

Nesse ponto já é possível utilizar $xml->body e quaisquer outros elementos.

No seu caso, acredito que seria algo do tipo

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result1[0]);
```

E poderia usar

```
$xml->G_ServApp_Response->consulta_disponivel->nome
```

Ou algo do tipo.

Fonte: [PHP.net simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

Comment: Já tentei este procedimento,mas tenho que digitar o xml, como uso PHP tentei coloca-lo em uma variavel pois pode ser que as informações sejam diferentes á cada busca,não consegui por enquanto.

Comment: Da forma como está no exemplo o objeto é criado dinâmicamente de acordo com a estrutura do XML. Da mesma forma que seria no caso do Json que você comentou. A partir do objeto gerado a sua aplicação deverá estar preparada para lidar com todos os retornos possíveis.

Comment: Será que as informações do webservice não correspondem a realidade? estão erradas?

Comment: Mesmo que retorne um erro do web service, isto deve ser previsto pelo seu código. seja na conversão do XML para Objeto, seja na verificação do cabeçalho http do retorno.

Comment: você tem como editar a pergunta com um exemplo de retorno xml diferente que pode ocorrer?

Comment: Adicionei um novo exemplo direcionado ao seu código

Comment: Usando:$xml = simplexml_load_string($result1[0]); dá o seguinte resultado:

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name in D:

Comment: Tente dar um `echo $result1[0]` para ver ser realmente está retornando somente o XML ou se está dentro de alguma outra estrutura, você deve passar para a função **simplexml_load_string** somente o texo/xml puro.

Comment: Dando um echo $result1[0] ----Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name in D:192 Warning: simplexml_load_string(): < in

Comment: Vendo a sua resposta abaixo, tente usar `$xml = simplexml_load_string($result1);` (sem usar a posição do array) acredito que funcione. Sobre o echo que você postou no ultimo comentário, era pra dar echo apenas no resultado ($result1[0]) e não na função simplexml_load_string().

Answer (score 1):

Pessoal achei uma solução(mas acho meio gambiarra!!!).
Peguei:

```
    $result1 = ( $client->__getLastResponse());
         var_dump($result1 );
        //Obtenho:
               array(1) {
                   [0]=>
                   string(701) "<G_ServApp_Response><consulta_disponivel><nome>LUIZ ALBERTO</nome>                                      <cartao>4332620000478720</cartao><proxy>0</proxy><limite_credito>0</limite_credito><disponivel_saques>0</disponivel_saques><disponivel_compras>0</disponivel_compras><saldo_atual>0</saldo_atual></consulta_disponivel><codigo_retorno>00</codigo_retorno></G_ServApp_Response>"
                  }
```

Fiz um explode:

```
$nome_arquivo = $result1;
       $arquivo = explode('nome', $nome_arquivo);
       print ("Portador" . $arquivo[1].'<br>');
       $arquivo = explode('cartao', $nome_arquivo);
       print ("Cartão" . $arquivo[1].'<br>');
       $arquivo = explode('proxy', $nome_arquivo);
       print ("Proxy" . $arquivo[1].'<br>');
       $arquivo = explode('limite_credito', $nome_arquivo);
       print ("Limite" . $arquivo[1].'<br>');
       $arquivo = explode('disponivel_saques', $nome_arquivo);
       print ("disponivel_saques" . $arquivo[1].'<br>');
       $arquivo = explode('disponivel_compras', $nome_arquivo);
       print ("disponivel_compras" . $arquivo[1].'<br>');
       $arquivo = explode('saldo_atual', $nome_arquivo);
       print ("saldo_atual" . $arquivo[1].'<br>');
       $arquivo = explode('codigo_retorno', $nome_arquivo);
       print ("codigo_retorno" . $arquivo[1].'<br>');
```

Obtive as respostas:

```
Portador>LUIZ ALBERTO</

Cartão>4332620000478720</

Proxy>0</

Limite>0</

disponivel_saques>0</

disponivel_compras>0</

saldo_atual>0</

codigo_retorno>00</
```

Só não senti firmeza em usar o `__getLastResponse`, percebo que é meio gato e verifiquei que o wsdl não tem separador.

Comment: As respostas ficaram com >0</ não consigo tirar nem com str_replace