# Como separar string que o soap gera?

Tags: php

```
if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
$client = new SoapClient('http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/fcthservices/mma.asmx?WSDL');

$function = 'Estado';

$options = array('location' => 'http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/fcthservices/mma.asmx');

$result = $client->__soapCall($function,$options);

var_dump($result);
?>
```

O resultado é isso:

> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["EstadoResult"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
>   ["any"]=> string(2956)
>   "URURUGUAIARARGENTINAPGPARAGUAICHCHILEBOBOLÍVIAPUPERUCOCOLÔMBIAEQEQUADORVEVENEZUELAGUGUIANASUSURINAMEGFGUIANA
>   FRANCESA11RORONDÔNIA12ACACRE13AMAMAZONAS14RRRORAIMA15PAPARÁ16APAMAPÁ17TOTOCANTINS21MAMARANHÃO22PIPIAUÍ23CECEARÁ24RNRIO
>   GRANDE DO
>   NORTE25PBPARAÍBA26PEPERNAMBUCO27ALALAGOAS28SESERGIPE29BABAHIA31MGMINAS
>   GERAIS32ESESPÍRITO SANTO33RJRIO DE JANEIRO35SPSÃO
>   PAULO41PRPARANÁ42SCSANTA CATARINA43RSRIO GRANDE DO SUL50MSMATO GROSSO
>   DO SUL51MTMATO GROSSO52GOGOIÁS53DFDISTRITO FEDERAL" } }

Não entendo eu preciso que o objeto venha separado.Porque o soap tá me retornando tudo junto. Tem como??

Comment: Exatamente o que esta retornando tudo junto? A string dentro do `any` ou o objeto como um todo?

Comment: Retorna esse ["any"]=> string(2956) com tudo junto! Mas o xml é separado. Dê uma olha aqui.

http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/fcthservices/mma.asmx/BaciaDataSet

Deveria vim com a estrutura do XML. A seguinte: 
Bacia diffgr:id="Bacia1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<Codigo>1</Codigo>
<Nome>RIO AMAZONAS</Nome>
</Bacia>

Comment: Era pra retorna um objeto estruturado com Bacia > codigo > nome. Entendeu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não precisa separar nada, o retorno provavelmente está em ordem e separado.

O problema é apenas o jeito que você está exibindo os dados na tela.

Pode ver que, inclusive, sua *string* entre aspas tem uns 480 caracteres, e o retorno indicado foi de 2956 caracteres. As tags retornadas não estão sendo mostradas na tela, pois o *browser* tenta interpretá-las.

Teste assim:

```
if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
$client = new SoapClient('http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/fcthservices/mma.asmx?WSDL');
$function = 'Estado';
$options = array('location' => 'http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/fcthservices/mma.asmx');
$result = $client->__soapCall($function,$options);

//VISUALIZAÇÃO EM HTML

// Vamos capturar a saída...
ob_start();
var_dump($result);
$saida = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

//e formatar para ver na tela:
echo nl2br( htmlentities( $saida ) );
```

Nota: dependendo do caso é melhor usar `print_r` no lugar do `var_dump`.

Para converter o XML em um objeto, já temos uma resposta no site:
**[Webservice SOAP com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33806/70)**

Comment: Muito bom. Mas tem como tirar as tags xml??? Deixar só os dados??
Exemplo: ["Sigla"]=> "UF", ["Estado"] => "São Paulo"....

Comment: O que eu queria mesmo era que ele não retornasse tudo dentro do ["any"], mas sim cada valor estruturado. Exemplo novamente:  ["Sigla"]=> "UF", ["Estado"] => "São Paulo"

Comment: Porque dessa forma eu vou poder manipular os valores do objeto de maneira fácil.

Comment: Aí basta uma pequena pesquisa no próprio site. Veja um exemplo funcional que achei imediatamente após seu comentário, simplesmente pesquisando por XML e PHP: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33806/70 - assim o XML vira um objeto, e vc pode acessar individualmente os membros.

Comment: Desculpa minha ignorância, mas não tenho muita experiência com webservices :(

Ficaria assim: 
//e formatar para ver na tela:
$saida = nl2br( htmlentities( $saida ) );
$xml = simplexml_load_string($saida->EstadoResult->any);

????

Comment: o load string é no $result, a parte da saída vc pode eliminar completamente. Só mostrei pra vc saber como visualizar na tela. Da parte que eu pus `//VISUALIZAR` em diante, pode apagar tudo no código definitivo, depois que verificar que está tudo ok.

Comment: Coloquei assim e funcionou!!! 
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result->EstadoResult->any);

Comment: Obrigado um milhãoooo de vezes!!! Você é fera!!!